# How can I keep track of which text entry is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I have a Tkinter Text widget with the text bound to a mouse click, how can I keep track of which text the user clicks on? I want the function to return the number of the label clicked, but as it stands it only prints the last value of n which is 5. For example, if the user clicks "Name 1", I want it to print "1", if the user clicks on "Name 2", I want it to return "2".

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def prt(num):
    print(num)

root = tk.Tk()

t = tk.Text(root, height=20, width=50)
t.pack()
for n in range(1, 6):
    t.insert(tk.END, "%s %d\n" % ("Name", n), "label")
    t.tag_bind("label", "<Button-1>", lambda event, num = n: prt(num))

root.mainloop()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: All of your text insertions use exactly the same tag name, so there's only one tag being created - whose click handler you overwrite multiple times.  Vary the name in the loop (`"label%d" % n`, perhaps) and I think it will work.

Comment: Yes you were right it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jasonharper for providing the answer. Here is the working code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def prt(num):
    print(num)

root = tk.Tk()

t = tk.Text(root, height=20, width=50)
t.pack()
for n in range(1, 6):

    t.insert(tk.END, "%s %d\n" % ("Name", n), "label%d" % n)

    t.tag_bind("label%d" % n, "<Button-1>", lambda event, num = n: prt(num))

root.mainloop()
```